# Resume Parser online demo

Tags: library, api, parser

I need an online demo of Resume Parser which would parse the resume that is uploaded by the user. It can be paid or free version.

I tried the following: [sovren](http://www.sovren.com/), [textkernel](http://www.textkernel.com/), [rchilli](http://rchilli.com), [hireability](http://www.hireability.com) and [zoho recruit](https://www.zoho.com/recruit/resume-parser.html)

But all of the above didn't have an online demo.  I need to see the online demo first.

Are there any recommendations?

Comment: I suggest you mail all of these companies with that request. That will not help you now, but maybe the idea lands that such a feature would benefit them. Obviously, you have already decided not to follow up with them because that's missing. It costs them customers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://affinda.com/resume-parser/ for free - the web interface allows you to upload resumes for free, and get the results as XLS, XML or JSON. The best part is you don't get forced to speak to a sales team!